# Are widgets the right place for simple controllers in Alloy?

Tags: widget, appcelerator

I'm just wondering if putting simple functionality into widget form is a good way to go when using Appcelerator with Alloy. I have a JS file which acts as a simple wrapper for the Ti HTTPClient and I want to incorporate it into my Alloy project. If I create a widget with the HTTP functionality in the widget.js file, a blank widget.tss file and a stub widget.xml file, will I be incurring extra overhead because of the unused UI functionality in the widget? Should I just stick to putting my HTTP.js file in the app/lib directory and requiring it in my Alloy controller files?

Comment: I think you meant to tag this as Alloy-UI; the 'Alloy' tag is for the lightweight formal methods tool developed at MIT.  So I'm taking the liberty of re-tagging the question; please correct my misapprehension if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks, @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen. That does sound a little closer to what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony Lukasavage answered this question for me on the Google Group for Alloy:

> > "If the code has no associated markup or tss styling, then yes, a commonjs module in app/lib would be the right choice"

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/appc-ti-alloy/pSlB5elTans